# Is this the best way to replace a Java object?

Tags: java, object, replace, instance

Sometimes i want to "replace" an object with another object of the same class.
Usually i do this in the following way.

The object's class with a constructor:

```
public class Type {

    private int field;
    private double anotherField;

    public Type(Type anotherTypeInstance) {
        this.field = anotherTypeInstance.getField();
        this.anotherField=anotherTypeInstance.getAnotherField();
    }
}
```

So whenever i want to replace the object I simply do this

```
Type oldInstance = new Type(newInstance)
```

Sometimes it is easy and convenient to do, while others not.
Is there an alternative?

EDIT:

I need this kind of "replacement" in optimization algorithms.
Where i have to replace the current Solution (object) whith another Solution that has a smaller cost

Comment: What you posted doesn't "replace" anything, it does a (form of) copy/clone. Please post a use case where it is "not convenient", or add more detail to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: There's the [Cloneable interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [`Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface and the [`clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) method like this

```
@Override
public Type clone() {
  try {
    return (Type) super.clone();
  } catch (CloneNotSupporedException cnse) {
    throw new RuntimeException(cnse); // Never happens.
  }
}
```

If you do use `clone()` for more complex classes, you need to make sure that all mutable objects referred to by fields of the class are recursively cloned as well, i.e. that you make a deep copy instead of a shallow copy. Accidental state sharing that can occur as a result of shallow copy can lead to problems which are hard to debug.

The use of `clone()` has a number of problems. It circumvents constructors which are normally a place where class's initial invariants are enforced. It is very error prone for classes containing more than just primitive types. Also, the use of `clone()` is incompatible with non-primitive final fields, since you cannot fix them after cloning an object in case they require modification to ensure deep copying.

Consider for example this class:

```
public class Car {
  private final Engine engine;

  // ... 

  @Override
  public Car clone() {
    try {
      Type copy = (Type) super.clone();
      copy.engine = (Engine) engine.clone(); // Error: final field cannot be modified.
      return copy;
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException cnse) {
      throw new RuntimeException(cnse);
    }
  }
}
```

Copy constructors like the one posted in the question are a much better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is fine. A better way would be:

```
public class Type {
    private int field;
    private double anotherField;

    @Override
    public Object clone() {
        Type anotherTypeInstance = new Type();
        anotherTypeInstance.field = field;
        anotherTypeInstance.anotherField=anotherField;
        return anotherTypeInstance;
    }
}
// Usage
Type object1 = new Type();
Type object1Cpy = (Type) object1.clone();
```

Comment: It is strongly recommended to implement the clone method by first calling `super.clone()`. Otherwise if a subclass is created (say `SubType`), it can not reuse the clone method of its parent since the parent class always returns an instance of class `Type` and not of `SubType`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) which is a standard way of creating a copy of existing object.

However I can't remember when was the last time I had to use `clone()`. Why do you need a copy of existing object that has exactly the same fields? Do you want to make changes to object without affecting the "original" one? Consider using immutable objects.

Comment: It's a way of creating a copy of an existing object - yes. But Note that clone() does NOT copy the fields. You'll have to override clone() and handle that yourself.

Comment: `Object.clone()` this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.